# How to set a String in a Option[String]?

Tags: scala

When I'm trying to affect a value of type String in a field of type Option[String] I get the following error :

```
type mismatch; found : String required: Option[String]
```

How can I affect value `myValue:String` into field `myField:Option[String]` ?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can also just use `Option(myValue)` which will convert null to `None` and non-null to `Some`.

Comment: You have to understand if you value is equal "" (empty string), option in this case will be Some()

Comment: Correct, an empty string is not the same as null.

Answer (score 19):

You can wrap any object in an `Option` like this:

```
val opt = Some("foo")
```

Comment: Note that you should use `Option(...)` in general to avoid getting a `Some(null)`, as one will usually pass a variable instead of a constant string.

Comment: also note that if you actually do have a constant string, it is better to use `Some("foo")`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to convert empty string to None more universal solution is: `Option(str).filter(_.nonEmpty)`

Answer (score 7):

You can just wrap your object in Some class

```
val myField = Some(myValue)
```

Or if you dont have Anything, pass

```
None
```

Its called Option pattern

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-option-pattern

Comment: `Option(...)` already does everything for you. It replaces `null` values by `None` and wraps the others in `Some(...)`. No need to make any distinction in your code there.

Comment: My point was to explain the option pattern like if you are using a custom api and want to pass nothing if value is empty.